# Matlab - latex format spacing

Tags: matlab, latex, legend, spacing, tex

I am creating a legend like so,

```
theta = [90 120 80 120];
phi   = [120 120 180 180];


for i=1:length(theta)
    plot_legend{i} = sprintf('\\theta=%3d\\circ\\phi=%3d\\circ',theta(i),phi(i))
end
```

This gives me my desired output

```
plot_legend = 
'\theta= 90\circ\phi=120\circ'
'\theta=120\circ\phi=120\circ'
'\theta= 80\circ\phi=180\circ'
'\theta=120\circ\phi=180\circ'
```

But when this is interpreted by the TeX interpreter, the leading space is neglected, which I find a tad annoying. Is there a simple TeX way to ensure that the spacing is maintained?

But the spacing is not maintained when called through legend.

```
legend(plot_legend,'interpreter','latex')
```

Comment: `\ ` (slash followed by a space) is one way to create whitespace in LaTeX, you could also try `\,`, for a comprehensive list, see [this answer on TeX.se](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74354), although some may not work with Matlab's LaTeX interpreter.

Comment: But I need the white space only for the 2digt case, and not the 3digit?

Comment: Do you want to add whitespace in the displayed legend? Or in the command window when you evaluate `plot_legend`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a general solution to replace the first padding zeros with LaTeX-interpreted spaces:

```
% --- Definition
theta = [5 120 80 120];
phi   = [120 120 180 180];

% --- The function handle that does the job
f = @(x, n) regexprep(num2str(x, ['%0' num2str(n) 'i']), '^(0+)', '${repmat(''\\hspace{0.5em}'', [1 numel($0)])}');

% --- Create a plot and the legend

hold on
for i = 1:length(theta)

    % Fake curve
    ezplot(['x^' num2str(i)]);

    plot_legend{i} = ['$\theta=' f(theta(i),3) '^\circ,\ \phi=' f(phi(i),3) '^\circ$'];
end

legend(plot_legend, 'interpreter', 'latex')
```

And the result:

[image]

You can specify the length of the number with the second parameter of the function handle. Note that this only works with integer values.

Best,

Comment: As I understand it, you use `regexprep` to replace each missing digit with a `/hspace` ?

Comment: Yes, regexprep replace all paddding zeros with spaces.

Comment: I just came across a unique case where theta=0, Is there someway for the regexp not to replace the units place with a `/hspace` and leave the same input character?

Comment: I just changed the regex to print leading 'x' 's instead and replaced them. Thanks for the idea!